# How to generate values in decimal from 1.00 to 1.99 in php and how to submit in post data one by one

Tags: php

I am trying to create a PHP that give decimal numbers from 1.00,1.01,1.02.....1.99 and I want to submit in post data like 1.00 and then 1.01 and then 1.02 and so on till 1.99. I have created some code.

```
for ($x = 1.00; $x <= 1.99; $x+=0.01)
{
  echo "$x\n";
}
```

And here is post data

```
$data="rs=$x";
```

When I try to submit post data, I get only 1.99 value in output, but I want all values from 1.00 to 1.99, please give some suggestion.

Comment: you have to use array

Answer (score 3):

Its really simple with using range..

```
$array = range(1.00, 1.99, 0.01);
var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a loop and you want to store all the values,

1- you can create an array and keep on appending the items in that array, and once the loop has ended you can submit that data in the array via the 'POST' method as you wished, or

2 - you can create a string variable outside the loop, and then keep on concatenating the string to the values, at the end of the loop you will have a variable that holds all the values from 1.00 to 1.99, and then you can send that variable data via post to the other side.

example:

```
$data = '';  // you can use an array here instead.

for ($x = 1.00; $x <= 1.99; $x+=0.01){

   $data .= $x;

}
```

and then you can send this variable 'data' via post,